# SQL insert into table based on results from group by query

Tags: sql-server

Have got one customer table which I want to delete any time that is older than 1 year.

Currently I have the following query which returns each individual customers time older than 1 year.

```
    select Customer, SUM(Time) as TimeTotal
    from CutomerTable
    WHERE Entry_Date_Time < DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    group by Customer
```

If possible, it would be good to insert into the customer table per customer a negative value for time older than a year into the time column. Currently I export the results into excel and do a line by line insert to update the table.

Any suggestions or some material that I should be reading would be great.

Sorry example

Example

```
Customer    Time        Entry_date_Time
1       30      2014-12-20 22:35:00.000                     
2       10      2014-12-20 22:35:00.000
3       15      2015-12-20 22:35:00.000
1       40      2015-12-20 22:35:00.000
```

Currently the table will show

```
Customer    Time
1       70
2       10      
3       15
```

I only want it to show time for the last year.

```
Customer    Time
1       40
2       0
3       15
```

Comment: your question is unclear. If you want to delete all rows having `entry_date_time` older than 1 year, you should simply do `DELETE FROM CutomerTable  WHERE Entry_Date_Time < DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` but the rest of your question is confusing

Comment: Post an example of data you have and corresponding set of rows you wish to obtain after data modification.

Comment: Have edited the first question. I don't want to delete information from the table as I want to use it at a later date. I want to add a negative value to the table to adjust the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain TimeTotal for period later than year but not later than two years ago (as shown in your example) then you need to set date range like below:

```
declare
  @datebegin  date,
  @dateend    date

set @dateend = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
set @datebegin = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @dateend)

select c.Customer, ct.TimeTotal_LastYear
from Customers c
left join
(
    select ct.Customer, SUM(Time) as TimeTotal
    from CutomerTable ct
    WHERE ct.Entry_Date_Time between @datebegin and @dateend
    group by ct.Customer
) t on ct.Customer = c.Customer
```

If you want to receive customers which don't have corresponding rows in period defined - use `left join` as shown in the script above or same scenario with `outer apply`.

#### Edit

Actually your example is confusing: filter applied is "older than a year ago", data shown - later than a year ago. If you need last year only then filter predicate has to be a bit simpler:

```
declare
  @datebegin  date

set @datebegin = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

select c.Customer, ct.TimeTotal_LastYear
from Customers c
left join
(
    select ct.Customer, SUM(Time) as TimeTotal
    from CutomerTable ct
    WHERE ct.Entry_Date_Time >= @datebegin
    group by ct.Customer
) t on ct.Customer = c.Customer
```

In your `groupby` approach you may reverse comparison from `<` to `>`.